# Is there a super fast compare byte[] method in Chronicle Bytes?

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-bytes

I'm storing a Murmur3 64-bit hash as a byte array in a Chronicle bytes object. I trying to sort these keys as fast as physically possible. I implemented quick sort to do that. I noticed there a set of compare and swap methods but nothing for a byte array. Is there anything I can use to speed up my quick sort? 
Profiling indicated that most pressure is on `net.openhft.chronicle.bytes.AbstractBytes.readCheckOffset(long, long, boolean) AbstractBytes.java`

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: BTW, I noticed switching off assertations (java -disableassertions) increases the performance of 30%. It's maybe worth to mention that in the documentation.

Comment: Assertions should be off by default, I am not sure why you would need to turn them off explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to compare two byte[] would be to use Unsafe to read an `int` or a `long` from the underlying arrays (and swap the byte order if little endian) This would give you a very fast comparison.

For the most part, Chronicle Bytes is designed to make it either to work with off heap memory though it also supports on heap e.g. byte[].